# How to properly segue from pickerView to MapKitView

Tags: ios, swift, segue

Salutations,

So I have a pickerView in my main ViewController, and in my ViewControllerTwo I have a singular mapKitView. My issue is that when I am trying to segue by clicking my button, my application crashes and throws an exception. Simply an NSException, this of course does not give me much.

The way I handle my segue is that I created one by manually dragging one from VC1 to VC2 and gave it the identifier of "viewMapSegue", then I also gave my button a tag of 1 as that is how I did a previous exercise and figured that by doing it this way I can ensure that the values are set to what I need at the time of the segue and not after.

All that being said, I am uncertain where I have erred. I know that if I use my VC2 code on its own with some hardcoded lat/long values that it runs fine and shows me the location I inputted. Code is below:

CityData:

```
import Foundation

class CityData {
    var cityName:String;
    var cityHighLight:String;
    var cityLat:Double;
    var cityLong:Double;

    init(cityName: String, cityHighLight:String, cityLat:Double, cityLong:Double) {
        self.cityName = cityName;
        self.cityHighLight = cityHighLight;
        self.cityLat = cityLat;
        self.cityLong = cityLong;
    }
}
```

VC1:

```
import UIKit


class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource{

    var globalRow : Int = 0;


    @IBOutlet weak var cityPicker: UIPickerView!;

    @IBAction func viewMap(button: UIButton) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "viewMapSegue", sender: button);
    }


    var data:[CityData] =
    [
        CityData(cityName:"Waycross", cityHighLight:"Alligators", cityLat: 31.214893, cityLong:-82.357244),
        CityData(cityName:"Athens", cityHighLight:"Heaven on Earth", cityLat: 33.946955, cityLong:-83.377878),
        CityData(cityName:"Plains", cityHighLight:"Peanuts", cityLat: 32.036008, cityLong:-84.393335),
        CityData(cityName:"Milledgeville", cityHighLight:"Mental Hospital", cityLat: 33.081313, cityLong:-82.233013),
        CityData(cityName:"Wrightsville", cityHighLight:"Home of Herschel", cityLat: 32.728958, cityLong:-82.719602)
    ];

//    var cityData:[String] = ["Waycross", "Plains", "Athens", "Milledgeville", "Wrightsville"];
//    var cityHighlights:[String] = ["Alligators", "Peanuts", "Heaven on Earth", "Mental Hospital", "Home of Herschel"];



    //number of columns
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1;
    }

    //number of rows
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return data.count;
    }

    //title for row
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {

        //dataFromPicker.text = data[row].cityHighLight;
       globalRow = row;

        return data[row].cityName;

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.cityPicker.dataSource = self;
        self.cityPicker.delegate = self;
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let lat = segue.destination as! ViewControllerTwo;
        let long = segue.destination as! ViewControllerTwo;

        if let button = sender as? UIButton {
            if button.tag == 1 {
                lat.latChosen = data[globalRow].cityLat;
                long.longChosen = data[globalRow].cityLong;

            }
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

And finally VC2 where the mapview is located:

```
//  ViewControllerTwo.swift
import UIKit
import MapKit

class ViewControllerTwo: UIViewController {

    var latChosen : Double = 0.0;
    var longChosen : Double = 0.0;


    @IBOutlet var myMap: MKMapView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        myMap.mapType = MKMapType.satellite;
        let initialLocation = CLLocation(latitude: latChosen, longitude: longChosen);
        let regionRadius: CLLocationDistance = 1000;

        func centerMapOnLocation(location : CLLocation) {
            let coordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(location.coordinate, regionRadius, regionRadius);
            myMap.setRegion(coordinateRegion, animated: true);
        }

        centerMapOnLocation(location: initialLocation);


    }



    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    }


    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}
```

[image: This is how the storyboard looks.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow....I cannot believe I did not think to check it earlier. So. apparently my button had two links, well one outlet that was connected as it should and another than came from god knows where. Wow....

ya know, apple really should give a warning like "hey, check your links, bro". Silent error that can drive people insane.